# While Importing counting lines :Unable to create single header for multiple lines

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365-operations

I have created custom data entity to import counting lines.In my dataentity I have InventJournalTable primary DS and  InventJournalTrans DS. I have used initializeEntityDataSource to set journalType and voucher series.But when import 2 lines of data it is creating two header data. But I want those 2 line data to be created in one single header. How do I do that?

Comment: Refer LedgerJournalEntity and modify that way.

Comment: I have already reffered that entity but still not able to resolve it